# Android api from browser

Tags: java, android, html, browser

I have a website. I'd like to create a 'mobile optimized' version.

My question is : can I use somehow the camera, gps, accelerometer API etc. from the browser (ex. embed java etc.) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This web video from google IO could give you a good answer : 
http://googlemonthly.com/google-directions/google-io-2011-html5-versus-android-apps-or-web-for-mobile-development.html

Reto meyer also published his slides here : 
http://www.slideshare.net/retomeier/html5-or-android-for-mobile-development

There are some solutions if you want to avoid a native app and prefer targetting html 5. Personnaly, I like too much java and OOP to get myself to deep in these technologies. Desktop and phones provide great APIs compared to the ever-patching-but-improving html/web technologies to my mind.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thank you, I am watching it now.